# Why are antiseptics used instead of topical antibiotics for pre-surgical skin sterilization?

Tags: pre-suregery-pre-op

Why do we use antiseptics to sterilize the skin prior to surgery instead of topical antibiotics?
Or is it that we have already given oral pre-operative antibiotics?

Is it a worry about developing topical antibiotic resistance?
Plus, antiseptics mainly target transient flora on the skin, how does that make it a more superior choice to topical antibiotics or a mix of other topical anti-infectives?

Comment: Antibiotics have no effect on viruses and most fungi.

Comment: They could still give a mix of other topical anti-infectives as I said in the end. They could still give topical anti-fungals with topical anti-virals, or is that not practical?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far? This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so I was sort of prompting you for what you've found so far. Antiseptics are cheap, available, and kill almost everything. What benefits could a more complex, expensive mixture bring to the table?